# Why should I not loop or block in Spout.nextTuple()

Tags: apache-storm

I saw many code snippets in which a loop was used inside `Spout.nextTuple()` (for example to read a whole file and emit a tuple for each line):

```
public void nextTuple() {
    // do other stuff here

    // reader might be BufferedReader that is initialized in open()
    String str;
    while((str = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        _collector.emit(new Values(str));
    }

    // do some more stuff here
}
```

This code seems to be straight forward, however, I was told that one should **not loop** inside `nextTuple()`. The question is why?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When a Spout is executed it runs in a single thread. This thread loops "forever" and has multiple duties:

1. call `Spout.nextTuple()`
2. retrieve "acks" and process them
3. retrieve "fails" and process them
4. time-out tuples

For this to happen, it is essential, that you do not stay "forever" (ie, loop or block) in `nextTuple()` but return after emitting a tuple to the system (or just return if no tuple can be emitted, but **do not block**). Otherwise, the Spout cannot does its work properly. `nextTuple()` will be called in a loop by Storm. Thus, after ack/fail messages are processed etc. the next call to `nextTuple()` happens quickly.

Therefore, it is also considered bad practice to emit multiple tuples in a single call to `nextTuple()`. As long as the code stays in `nextTuple()`, the spout thread cannot (for example) react on incoming acks. This might lead to unnecessary time-outs because acks cannot be processed timely.

Best practice is to emit a single tuple for each call to `nextTuple()`. If no tuple is available to be emitted, you should return (without emitting) and not wait until a tuple is available.