# How to set TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING parameter

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-storm

In my topology, I read trigger messages from a Kafka queue. On receiving the trigger message, I need to emit around 4096 messages to a bolt. In the bolt, after some processing it will publish to another Kafka queue (another topology will consume this later).

I'm trying to set `TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING` parameter to throttle the number of messages going to bolt. But I see it is having no effect. Is it because I'm emitting all the tuples in one `nextTuple()` method? If so, what should be the work around?

Comment: What code have you tried?

Comment: I've edited your post to include formatting tags, and also fixed a few typos. The clearer the question, the better the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you are reading from kafka, you should use the `KafkaSpout` that comes packed with storm. Don't try to implement your own spout, trust me, I use the KafkaSpout in production and it works very smoothly. Each Kafka message generates exactly one tuple.

And as you can see on [this nice page from the manual](https://storm.apache.org/documentation/Running-topologies-on-a-production-cluster.html), you can set the `topology.max.spout.pending` like this:

```
Config conf = new Config();
conf.setMaxSpoutPending(5000);
StormSubmitter.submitTopology("mytopology", conf, topology);
```

The `topology.max.spout.pending` is set per spout, if you have four spouts you will have a maximum of non-complete tuples inside your topology equal to the number of spouts * topology.max.spout.pending.

Another tip, is that you should use the storm UI to see if the `topology.max.spout.pending` was set properly.

---

Remember the `topology.max.spout.pending` is only the number of tuples not unprocessed inside the topology, the topology will never stop consume messages from kafka, at least on a production system... If you want to consume batches of 4096 you need to implement caching logic on your bolts, or use something else than storm (something micro batch oriented).

Comment: Thanks for the response.

Answer (score 1):

To make TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING you need to enable fault-tolerance mechanism (ie, assigning message IDs in Spouts and anchor and ack in Bolts). Furthermore, if you emit more than one tuple per call to `Spout.nextTuple()` TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING will not work as expected.

It is actually bad practice for some more reasons so emit more than a single tuple per `Spout.nextTuple()` call (see [Why should I not loop or block in Spout.nextTuple()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547935/why-should-i-not-loop-or-block-in-spout-nexttuple) for more details).

Comment: Thanks Matthias for the reply. I see the problem here, as I am emitting all the 4096 tuple for a single message. However, that is something my use-case requires me to do.

Comment: Maybe you can set TOPOLOGY_MAX_SPOUT_PENDING to one. This should trigger a single call to `nextTuple()` and will not issue a second call until all 4096 tuples you emit got processed.

Comment: Thanks Matthais for the reply. I'll rethink on the topology design that I have.