# Apache Storm: Limit the number of tuples produced (in a certain time frame)

Tags: apache-storm

By my understanding `ack`, `fail` and `nextTuple` functions are called using the same thread in a tight loop as ISpout Javadoc suggest:

> nextTuple, ack, and fail are all called in a tight loop in a single
>   thread in the spout task.

Say we have a synthetic tuple generator and we want to limit the number of tuples emitted by the spout per second. How can that be achieved? Is putting a sleep() a good idea? Is there an alternative way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A sleep might not be the best idea because it blocks the spout to process incoming acks. See here: [Why should I not loop or block in Spout.nextTuple()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547935/why-should-i-not-loop-or-block-in-spout-nexttuple)

I would just count the emitted tuples and remember a timestamp. If the number of tuples per time unit is exceeded and the time unit did not pass, just return from `nextTuple()` without emitting any tuple. When the time unit passed, reset the counter to zero, advance the timestamp by the time unit, and resume emitting. And so fourth.

Comment: Yup that's what I thought that it wasn't a good idea to sleep. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: Just extended my answer.