# Which supervisor will be listening through its spout?

Tags: apache-storm

In my topology I have a spout with a socket opened on port 5555 to receive messages.

If I have 10 supervisors in my Storm cluster, will each one of them be listening to their 5555 ports?

In the end, to which supervisor should I send messages?

Comment: seem like you need to use poll instead of push or use other design like middle man / lb ..

Answer (score 1):

Multiple comments here:

- Storm uses a pull based model for data ingestion via Spouts. If you open a socket you will block the Spout until data is available (and this is bad; see this SO question for more details: [Why should I not loop or block in Spout.nextTuple()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32547935/why-should-i-not-loop-or-block-in-spout-nexttuple))
- About Spout deployment (Supervisors):

  - first, it depends on the parallelism of your spout (ie,`parallelims_hint`, default value is one)
  - second, supervisors do no execute Spout code: Supervisors start up worker JVM that execute Spouts/Bolts (see config parameter `number_of_workers` for a topology)
  - third, Storm uses a load-balanced round-robin scheduler; thus, it might happen that two Spout executor are scheduled to the same worker JVM (or different workers on the same host); for this case, you will get a port conflict (only one execute will be able to open the port)
- Dated distribution should not matter in this case: if you really go with push, you can choose any host to send the data; Storm does not care. Of course, if you need some kind of key-based partitioning, you might want to send data from a single partition the a single Spout instance; as an alternative, just forward the data within the Spout and use `fieldsGrouping` to get your partitions for the consuming Bolt. However, if you use pull based data ingestion by the Spout, you can ensure that each Spout pulls data from certain partitions and the problem resolves naturally.

To sum up: using push based data ingestion might be a bad idea.